# Did Github remove support for rendering mdx?

Tags: github, mdx

In a few private repositories for the company I work for, we have MDX files. Previously it seemed that these files rendered like Markdown. However today on Github they are displaying as plain text (raw). Did Github remove support for rendering these files? Or is this the Mandella effect and my team and I mis-remember that this ever was a feature?